# zk: extending Datebox and Calendar widgets

Tags: java, calendar, widget, zk, datebox

I have to modify Datebox and CalendarPop (Calendar) components in the way that if I give them a particular date/dates the Calendar of Datebox would show those dates with the particular CSS (for instance dates of holidays).

I haven't done anything before with the widget extension. I already checked Datebox.js sources and have no idea how to override `_initPopup()` function, where `zul.db.CalendarPop()` is initialized.

Maybe there is another approach to achieve what I want or I am doing something wrong?

Any information will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can use *zk.override()* to override a ZK widget class.

For example,

```
(function () {
    var _oldPop = {};

zk.override(zul.db.CalendarPop.prototype, _oldPop, {
    setXXX: function () {
        // override XXX function here.
        _oldPop.setXXX.apply(this, arguments); // invoke the original one if needed.
    }
});

})();
```

As long as the overridden code can be run before that *setXXX* function invoked.